# Specify returnType: DataType in UDFRegistration.register()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[Scala API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration@register(name:String,f:org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2[_,_,_],returnType:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType):Unit) says that register(..) accepts returnType.But when I do and compile, I get the following error.

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
    .config("spark.serializer", classOf[KryoSerializer].getName)
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.udf.register("doIt", do_it_func, ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
    StructField("V1", DoubleType),
    StructField("V2", DoubleType),
    StructField("V3", DoubleType)))))

  def do_it_func: String => Seq[(Option[Double], Option[Double], Option[Double])] = {
    (s, r1, r2) => Seq((None, None, None))
  }
```

```
error: overloaded method value register with 
alternatives:[ERROR]   (name: String,f: 
org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF22[_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, 
_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _],returnType: 
org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)Unit [ERROR]   (name: String,f: 
org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF21[_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, 
_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _],returnType: 
org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)Unit
```

Why can't I pass in returnType?

Thanks, 
Kyunam